# Creating seaborn displot with loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

What i would like to do is creating displots in a way that each pair of two occupies a row. So, i used these lines of codes:

```
columns = list(cols) # cols created from dataframe.columns
sns.set(rc = {"figure.figsize": (12, 15)})
sns.set_style(style = "white")

for i in range(len(columns)):
    plt.subplot(10, 2, i + 1)
    sns.displot(data[columns[i]], rug = True)
```

However, the result is a runtime error and strange shaped plots.
[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8lqU.png)

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: How many plots are you trying to create?

Comment: @Luke I am trying to create 20 plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sns.displot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) is a [figure-level function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions) and always creates its own new figure. To get what you want, you could create a [long-form](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data) dataframe.

Here is some example code showing the general idea:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(30, 20), columns=[*'abcdefghijklmnopqrst'])
cols = data.columns
data_long = data.melt(value_vars=cols)
g = sns.displot(data_long, x='value', col='variable', col_wrap=2, height=2)
g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.97, bottom=0.07, left=0.07, hspace=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.displot using long data]